# IAM role fails to give permission to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to run `aws ec2 describe-instances` in an AWS EC2.

So I attach an IAM role to the EC2. This IAM role contains `AmazonEC2FullAccess`, and `AmazonS3FullAccess` permissions.

[image]

I then execute `aws ec2 describe-instances` command in the EC2.

But I get `You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".` as the return message.

Why doesn't `AmazonEC2FullAccess` give the permissions required to run `aws ec2 ...` to the EC2?

I can successfully run `aws s3 ls` command in the EC2.

This seems to imply that `AmazonS3FullAccess` successfully grants permission to the EC2, but `AmazonEC2FullAccess` fails to grant the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region is required for the AWS CLI:

For example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1
```

It worked for S3, because (I think) S3 bucket names have global scope. Instances are regional only.

Similarly, you can run `iam`, `route53` or `cloudfront` commands without region as they have global scope, e.g.

```
aws iam list-users

aws route53 list-hosted-zones

aws cloudfront list-distributions
```